# How to prevent laravel auto redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I deployed a laravel app in a sub folder of my shared hosting. The application displays fine when I visit domain.com/index.php, but when I try domain.com it redirects to domain.com/public/app-name.

**Note**: I created a subdomain with the other site pointing to that path, it works perfectly.
 Thanks.

Comment: Please share your some code

Comment: Not a Laravel question, seems more like an Apache or NGINX misconfiguration, share your configuration for us to help you

Comment: this is more on the web server configuration. double check your nginx , apache, iis or whatever web engine that you are using.